# What algorithm constructs the optimal code $f$ of size $a$?

Tags: information-theory, data-compression

I'm looking at [Shannon's source coding theorem for symbol codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem#Source_coding_theorem_for_symbol_codes). It provides a very nice bound on the expected code length $S=|f(X)|$ of an optimal code $f$ over the sequence variable $X$:

$$
\frac{H(X)}{log_2(a)} \le \mathbb{E}[S] \lt \frac{H(X)}{log_2(a)} + 1
$$

It does not however prescribe an algorithm that can learn an optimal code $f$ with size $a$ for a data set of sequences $D=\{D_0, D_1, ...\}$, where $D \stackrel{iid}{\sim} X$

In pseudocode, I think it would look something like:

$$
f = learn(D, a)
$$
$$
T_i = encode(D_i, f)
$$
$$
D_i = decode(T_i, f)
$$

Is there an algorithm for that?

One trivial example is, if $a \ge |D|$, we could set $f=D$ and say $T_i = (i)$, which guarantees length 1, however I'm more interested in the $a \ll |D|$ regime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Arithmetic codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding) can get arbitrarily close to the Shannon limit, assuming your model of probabilities is correct. It it typically shown in the context of a binary alphabet, but there's nothing fundamental about that. It can work in any radix, as well as mixed-radix systems.